# Remove parts of image by thickness using opencv and python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

Due to prior processing steps i have the following image:
[image]

And my task is to remove the parts of the image having thickness under a certain value. To remove those vertical lines, of course, keeping only the text box. Note that **those line can be horizontal as well, but not obliques**.

I've tried with `cv2.erode`, but if affects, obviously, every part of the image:

```
 cv2.erode(masked_text_box, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2,2) ))
```

and the text in particular. Being the next step of the pipeline a OCR script, i cannot allow the text to lose sharpness, so maybe a more geometry-based approach could be a better choice.
Is there a smart way to filter out pixels that have less than `N` not black pixel in their neighbourhood? *Smart* meaning not the `bruteforce` way: for every pixel on the image, check the color of the neighbours, etc...

### Edit

As suggested in the comments box, given that the borders are all in (0, 255, 0) green, for this specific case the simplest solution is to transform those greens in black (0,0,0). Something like this will do the trick:

```
masked_text_box[np.all(masked_text_box == (0, 255, 0), axis=-1)] = (0,0,0)
```

But i'll leave the question open in case of more general or different solution.

Comment: what about getting the pixels with that exact tone of green set to 0?

Comment: Yes, it works: `masked_text_box[np.all(masked_text_box == (0, 255, 0), axis=-1)] = (0,0,0)`, thank you

Comment: I would put a bit of margin about the color. If your image is stored in a compressed format you might have deviations from that color that you want to take in account

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, but if i got your point: this is an intermediate stage i'm producing (and not storing) having read once and for all the image at the beginning of the pipeline, so i think the green will remain green. Did i got your point?

Comment: @AlessandroTogni Your `erode` function uses a rectangular kernel of size 2x2. You can try using similar kernel but with size 2xH and/or Wx2 for vertical/horizontal lines

Comment: @JeruLuke It kind of work, but i'm concerned by the eventuality both horizontal and vertical lines are present. In that case a vertical kernel would be uneffective or worst agains horizontal ones, and viceversa.